# How to override libraryDependencies in a sbt plugin?

Tags: scala, sbt

How would one override the `libraryDependencies` ?
I tried:

```
  Keys.libraryDependencies in Compile := {
    val libraryDependencies = (Keys.libraryDependencies in Compile).value
    val allLibraries = UpdateDependencies(libraryDependencies)
    allLibraries
  }
```

So that seem to work, when I add print statement, the `allLibraries` is correct.

However, in the next steps, it doesn't seem to have the right values:

```
  Keys.update in Compile := Def.taskDyn {
    val u = (Keys.update in Compile).value

    Def.task {
      val allModules= u.configurations.flatMap(_.allModules)
      log.info(s"Read ${allModules.size} modules:")
      u
    }
  }.value
```

The print statement only have a few modules instead of all the one I would have added in the previous step.

Anyone have a solution ? Thanks !

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "override"? Like the build user adds some library X 1.0, and you want to remove it and add Y 1.0 instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I understand where my problem was. 
I was not understanding correctly how `settings` and `tasks` were working together.

`settings` are only evaluated once when `sbt` start.

and `tasks` are only evaluated once when `sbt` start a task / command which will require it.

So you cannot read and then rewrite `settings` like that.

It was so convoluted, I even [wrote a whole article about it](https://leobenkel.com/2018/11/make-sbt-plugin/#how-to-override-a-setting-)